# Deleting Rows between text

Tags: excel, delete-row, vba

I have a long complex macro that I keep adding text to in order to improve. Right now it's perfect except for one last pet peeve item. Basically there is a report that we dump to excel and the macro formats the report, however sometimes the report is more than one page and there are two headers. I want to remove one header, but keep the other. Obviously the header is between different text depending on where the page break lands. I was able to write code to find certain things and delete the rows, however that deletes the page 1 header as well which I want to keep. These are financial statements and the header text is this:

Report ID: DC_COMPINC
Format ID: VARSUM
Reforecast Bud: MFC09
Style ID: @

However there are a bunch of blank rows as well. I'm not sure if this can be done, and certainly manually deleting the text is not a big deal I am just trying to automate as much as possible. From what I can tell there are a total of 10 rows that need to be deleted, the first 4 are the text above, plus 6 blank rows below that.

Answer (score 1):

If the header always starts with the same specific characters you can loop through the rows, find any secondary instances of the header text, and remove the desired set of rows. In the code below you need to specify the CommonHeaderText string as well as the first cell in the report.

```
Sub HeaderRemover()

' dim the variables
Dim FirstCell As Range
Dim CommonHeaderText, DeletionRowString As String
Dim HeaderInstances As Integer

' modify to grab the right header and start in the right place
CommonHeaderText = "Test Header"
Set FirstCell = Range("A1")

' initialize the counter
HeaderInstances = 0

' loop through the rows, removing extra header lines
For i = 0 To FirstCell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    ' check if header text starts the specific cell
    If CommonHeaderText = Left(FirstCell.Offset(i), Len(CommonHeaderText)) Then
        HeaderInstances = HeaderInstances + 1
        ' remove the desired rows if this is this isn't the first instance of the header text
        If HeaderInstances > 1 Then
            ' remove 10 sequential rows, starting 3 rows before the header row
            DeletionRowString = i - 2 & ":" & i + 7
            Rows(DeletionRowString).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Note if there are blank rows the FirstCell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count won't work properly. You could do something clever or just hard code a sufficiently large integer since this isn't very computationally intensive.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I tried that, replacing "Test Header" with "*report ID*" and it didn't work. I'm thinking it's because there are some blank rows? This is an income statement and there are blank rows in between categories (i.e. Total Revenue, blank row Total Recoverable Expenses, blank row etc etc) but honestly VBA is not my thing. I'm VERY good with excel, but the VBA stuff has always eluded me.

Comment: If you have blank lines change the 'For i = 0 To FirstCell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count' line to instead read 'For i = 0 to 1000' where 1000 is larger than the maximum number of rows in your spreadsheet. That will force it to look for "report ID" on the first 1000 lines of the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Just pre-read the initial header into your buffer to preserve it before you run your sterilization code to ignore the rest of the page headers. If you know the header is 10 lines, then you can prebuffer the first ten lines. Even if the header record was of a variable length, you'd only have to pre-buffer up until you reach the first line that you identify to be data and not a header line. So basically (in pseudo-code):

```
    currLine = readLine(inputFile)

    do while not isData(currLine) {          
    \\ isData(string) would compare the string to criteria you identify as a data record
        fileBuffer = fileBuffer + currLine   \\ Add the header line to the string buffer for the file
        currLine = readLine(inputFile)  \\ Read the next line
    }

   \\ At this point you've segregated the one header that you want 
   \\ so read the rest of the file

    do while not endOfFile(inputFile) {
        if isData(currLine) {
        \\ Add the line to the buffer only if it appears to be a data line
           fileBuffer = fileBuffer + currLine
        }
        currLine = readLine(inputFile) \\ Read the next line
    }

    \\ Actually, the way this is formatted, you'd have to handle the 
    \\ last line after the loop exits but that can be averted in VB 
    \\ by handling the loop conditions at the end
```

Alternatively, if you didn't want to read the entire file into a buffer first and would prefer to place send the lines you want directly to the report, you can just use a boolean flag to identify if you've already read your initial header... so for example, you set the flag to false, then once the first data line has been read, you set it to true... all the while you are conditionally sending lines to the report on if the flag is false or the line is data.